# How to implement HashIds in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

(edit:  I have read and re-read the github pages, that's how I know there is a (parial) tsql version of hashids.

I have also read and re-read the "The command below will generate a set of TSQL encode functions and test objects into the test.sql file."

My question (which obviously was not to clear) is HOW do I run this command?  Typing "npm ..." in my command prompt does not work.

Do I type the "npm..." into a new query in my sql server?  In a specific database?  In (doubltful) Visual Studio project?

Thanks to everyone that has taken the time to read and provide their insights.

chuck

I would like to use [hashids.org/tsql](https://hashids.org/tsql/) on my server, but I do not know how to add this functionality to the server.

What I am missing (at least to start with) is how make the "dbo.encode1" possible?

Thank you,
chuck

Comment: advertisment? as the readme.md in GitHub is very clear about the installation.

Comment: I don't think it's an advertisement because all of it seems to be open source, so it will be difficult to make money with it. Probably the OP just hasn't found the Github home page .. I first have missed that link as well.

Comment: Not an advertisement.  Asking a legitimate question in a field (sql database admin) I am not an expert in, in a portion (functions) that I have not worked with.

Comment: Please remove that question from "put on hold". It is quite clear what the OP is asking. He wants to use hashids.org/tsql with his SQL server, but just did not know what `npm` is and how to use it. I am considering this a legitimate question and therefore have tried to explain in my answer. IMHO, we can't expect that a database admin has heard of NodeJS or npm. I think that similar mistakes have happened to the most of us ...

Comment: Binarus - that is exactly what I was trying to get to.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the page you linked, there is a link to the Github page of that project. That page contains installation instructions. The page is at:

https://github.com/waynebloss/hashids-tsql

Excerpt:

> The command below will generate a set of TSQL encode functions and test objects into the test.sql file.
>
> ```
> npm install -g hashids-tsql
>
> hashids-tsql -t test.sql
> ```

**EDIT 1**

The OP commented that this exactly is what he didn't know how to do. So I'll shortly explain:

`npm` is the package manager of `node.js`, which is basically a very well-known JavaScript interpreter for the command line. You can download it [here](https://nodejs.org/en/), together with packages you might need. But be prepared that you will need a little bit of time until you have understood its concepts. There are countless tutorials and articles covering the basic steps, though.

If you have access to a reasonable Linux distribution, you can install `node.js` (sometimes written as `nodejs` or `NodeJS`) using the package manager of your distribution.

To summarize:

- Download and install NodeJS.
- Download and install `npm` (NodeJS package manager); depending on your environment, `npm` might be provided as a standalone installer, or you could install it from within NodeJS.
- Run the commands shown on `hashids-tsql`'s GitHub page; this will generate the `test.sql` file, using NodeJS / npm.

Comment: I saw that, it is that that is stumping me.  HOW?

Comment: Please have a look at my EDIT 1.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks to binarus for the assist.